# Issue updating database (MYSQL, php, Javascript) using FormData and xhr Request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web, form-data

I have a Data Base through MYSQL. I am building the "Admin" section of a website, where Admin users can go in, upload files, and then the MYSQL data base is updated. It was previously working and then stopped about 24 hrs and I still can't figure out exactly what the issue is. This is my code and a wide explanation of what it is doing:

First, there are dropdown boxes. There are different tables in MYSQL, each with different categories and subcategories. The user can select to use one of those categories or to create a new one. When they create a new one, then they enter the new name on an input box. They also enter other parameters such as a title, a source, etc (these are all table columns in MYSQL). I am putting all these parameters in a FormData, then sending a POST request to a php page that handles the queries. This code won't throw any errors, but no new entry will be created in MYSQL.
Something quiet odd is, there was a point on which I had an error calling some of the elements in the page, and whenever those errors were there then MYSQL would actually create a new entry. (It would lack 2 parameters, the chartType and the content). After fixing that error, the entry won't be created again. Is there a possibility I am sending my request wrong? (I have added a comment on the code where the error I am talking about was)

Some things I tried doing: I added enctype=multipart/form-data on my form (I added this mainly because my console was telling me it was missing since users upload an excel file), and I also got rid of the "document.forms("myonlyform").submit" line. Still not working. I have added the php code on here too, which is the section that handles the query. It comes after the javascript part.

```
    tableArray = table.getData();
    console.log("This tableArray");
    console.log(tableArray);
    let menu = document.getElementById("menu-selection").value;
    let level1Value = document.getElementById("selection-level1").value; //These are input boxes
    let level2Value = document.getElementById("selection-level2").value;
    let level3Value = document.getElementById("selection-level3").value;
    let level1NewValue="";
    let level2NewValue="";
    let level3NewValue="";
    if (document.getElementById("selection-level1").value=='new'){
        level1NewValue=document.getElementById("new-category-name").value; //This is where the error I mentioned was. It was simply that my ID was incorect, but this somehow caused mysql to create the new entry (without a couple parameters). 
        
    }
    if (document.getElementById("selection-level2").value=='new'){ 
        level2NewValue=document.getElementById("new-sub-category-name").value; 
        console.log(level2NewValue);
    }
    if (document.getElementById("selection-level3").value=='new'){
        level3NewValue=document.getElementById("new-sub-sub-category-name").value; 
        console.log(level3NewValue);
    }
    let title1=document.getElementById("title").value; //Input boxes as well
    let source1=document.getElementById("source").value;
    let chartType1=document.getElementById('chartType').value;
    let chartType2=getChartTypeObject(); //This is a function that returns a chartType in order to build one later on
    var contentInput = document.getElementById('content');
    contentInput.value = JSON.stringify(tableArray);
    let Input=JSON.stringify(tableArray);
    console.log("This Input");
    console.log(Input);
    console.log("This contentInput");
    console.log(contentInput.value);
    
    const fd1=new FormData();
    fd1.append("action", "create");
    fd1.append("menu-selection",menu);
    fd1.append("selection1", level1Value);
    fd1.append("selection2",level2Value);
    fd1.append("selection3",level3Value);
    fd1.append("newSelection1",level1NewValue);
    fd1.append("newSelection2",level2NewValue);
    fd1.append("newSelection3",level3NewValue);
    fd1.append("title",title1);
    fd1.append("source",source1);
    fd1.append("chartType",chartType2);
    fd1.append("content",Input);
    const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "datasetQuery.php",true);
    xhr.responseType='json';
    xhr.onload=()=>{
        stres=xhr.response;
        console.log("This New Request");
        console.log(stres);
    }
    console.log("This fd1: ");
    console.log(fd1);
    xhr.send(fd1);
    document.forms["myonlyform"].submit();
    
}

if(isset($_POST)){

    $action=$_POST["action"];
    $menu = $_POST["menu-selection"];
    $level1=$_POST["selection1"];
    $level2=$_POST["selection2"];
    $level3=$_POST["selection3"];


    if($_POST["selection1"]=="new"){
      $level1= $_POST["newSelection1"];
    }

    if($_POST["selection2"]=="new"){
      $level2 = $_POST["newSelection2"];
    }

    if($_POST["selection3"]=="new"){
      $level3 = $_POST["newSelection3"];
    }

    var_dump($_POST);


    $title= $_POST["title"];
    $note=$_POST["note"];
    $source= $_POST["source"];
    $chartType = $_POST["chartType"];
    $content=$_POST["content"];
    $query = new Query(); 

    if($action=="create"){
        $query->addNewMenuItem($menu, $level1, $level2, $level3, $title, $content, $source,$chartType,$note );
 
    }

    if($action=="update"){  
      $query->updateMenuItem($menu, $level1, $level2, $level3, $title, $content, $source,$chartType, $note );
  
  }
  if($action=="delete"){ 
$query->deleteMenuItem($menu, $level1, $level2, $level3 );
}



}


public function addNewMenuItem($menu, $level1, $level2, $level3, $title, $content,$source,$chartType){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$menu`  (`id`,`level1`,`level2`,`level3`,`title`,`dat`,`source`,`chartType`,`time`) values (NULL, '$level1', '$level2', '$level3', '$title','$content', '$source' ,'$chartType',NOW())";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: `document.forms["myonlyform"].submit();`... this will submit the form normally and cancel your AJAX request

Comment: I have tried deleting this line, but still nothing.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? This question is tagged with PHP and MySQL, but does not contain such code

Comment: @NicoHaase True. Sorry. I have added it. What was missing was the php section which handles the query. It takes the info given by $POST and adds the necessary fields onto the database (or it's supposed to). I have added logs to every entry of the formdata too, and everything seems correct.

Comment: Please be warned that the given query is widely open for SQL injection. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem (where the browser does not send the AJAX request properly), or a PHP problem (where the server does not handle the request properly)?

Comment: @NicoHaase I would say this is a PHP problem. As shown in the code, when I tried var_dump on $POST it is receiving all the information I meant to send to it, it just seems to never create the SQL entry.

Comment: I have actually figured out what the issue was and it was all about the excel file containing apostrophes and messing up the string when it was sent to query.